# Using eval within a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I want to evaluate the value of a dict key, using the dict itself.
For example:

```
dict_ = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':'x+y'}
dict_['z'] = eval(dict_['z'], dict_)
print(dict_)
```

When I do this it includes a bunch of unnecessary stuff in the dict. In the above example it prints:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, '__builtins__': bunch-of-unnecessary-stuff-too-long-to-include
```

Instead, in the above example I just want:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

How to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass a copy of dict to `eval()`:

```py
dict_ = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": "x+y"}

dict_["z"] = eval(dict_["z"], dict_.copy())
print(dict_)
```

Prints:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

Comment: It seems silly to pass a copy, but it works, thank you!

Comment: When you pass `_dict` to `eval()` as the second parameter it becomes the global namespace inside `eval()`. Python is in control of that global namespace and does things with it you don't expect.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you for the explanation, it makes sense now whay I was getting those bunch-of-unnecessary-stuff!

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the formula in the dict. Have it access the values in the dict. The problem is you haven’t defined `x` or `y`

```
dict_ = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': "dict_['x']+dict_['x']"}
dict_['z'] = eval(dict_['z'])
```

Comment: It gives me `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`. May be I am missing something?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this works now! Only issue with this approach (for my case) is that the value of 'z' is already present in the dict as an expression (it can be 'any' kind of expression that can be evaluated) and parsing that expression to convert to a dict lookup format will be complicated. So for my case the other answer with passing a copy of dict to eval works better (and thus accepted that answer). I appreciate your answer and the explanation though, thank you!

Comment: Makes total sense. I was trying to figure out why it wasn’t working in the first place. I accidentally copied a bad character. I’ve updated the code back to what it originally was without the bad character. This should work as you expect now.